# Semantic element to create a toggle and best practice to undo a function

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle

Sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Toggle</title>
    <style>
        #first {
            color: blue;
        }
        #second {
            border: 1px solid green;
        }
        #third {
            background: tan;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <label for="box">Toggle</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="box" onchange="toggle();">
    <div id="first">First</div>
    <div id="second">Second</div>
    <div id="third">Third</div>
    <script>
        function toggle() {
            var box = document.getElementById('box');
            var first = document.getElementById('first');
            var second = document.getElementById('second');
            var third = document.getElementById('third');
            if (box.checked) {
                first.style.color = 'red';
                second.style.border = '2px dotted blue';
                third.style.background = 'olive';
            } else {
                first.style.color = 'blue';
                second.style.border = '1px solid green';
                third.style.background = 'tan';
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RainLover/3fNre/)**

I wonder if an `input checkbox` is the right element to create a toggle. I also want to know how to undo what I have in the `if` clause: in `else` do I have to repeat my stylesheet or is there a shorter neater way to get back to the initial state?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/anandnat/3fNre/3/

Comment: As mentioned in my question I'm looking for a JavaScript approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in better way like this: **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3fNre/2/)**

Add a parent div in html like this:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="first">First</div>
    <div id="second">Second</div>
    <div id="third">Third</div>
</div>
```

Then handle your front end with css instead inline styling:

```
.checked #first {
    color:red;
}
.checked #second {
    border:2px dotted blue;
}
.checked #third {
    background:olive;
}
```

Then add and remove only one class with javascript:

```
function toggle() {
        var box = document.getElementById('box');
        var parent = document.getElementById('parent');

        if (box.checked) {
            parent.className = parent.className + "checked";
        } else {
            parent.className = "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your approach seems perfect! But in your demo why didn't you use the `<body>` tag as the parent instead of adding another HTML element?

Comment: I wonder what you think of this: [one line of javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/Mori/3xYw4/)

Answer (score 1):

**1. I wonder if an input checkbox is the right element to create a toggle?**

Definition of toggle*:

> COMPUTING a key or command that is operated the same way but with
>   opposite effect on successive occasions.

Explanation of checkbox**:

> In computing, a checkbox (check box, tickbox, or tick box) is a
>   graphical user interface element (widget) that permits the user to
>   make a binary choice, i.e. a choice between one of two possible
>   mutually exclusive options.

So yes, it is the best choice.

**2. I also want to know how to undo what I have in the if clause: in else do I have to repeat my stylesheet or is there a shorter neater way to get back to the initial state?**

In order to do this you could using jQuery:

Use either `addClass()`/`removeCLass()` methods or `toggleClass()`; You would put your active class stylings into a new class, apply these then simply remove them on the `else`/off state. This would also mean you maintain the separation between contents and styling.

Or regular JS:

`.setAttribute("class", "active");` and `.removeAttribute("class", "active");` or simply `.removeAttribute("style");` to unset the styles you applied inline and revert to the original state.

*[Source](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%20toggle&oq=define%20toggle&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1567j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3atoggle)

**[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checkbox)

Comment: Many thanks for the confirmation and explanations! :)

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second question:

You could use `getElementById("id").removeAttribute("style");` to remove inline styles.

```
if (box.checked) {
    first.style.color = 'red';
    second.style.border = '2px dotted blue';
    third.style.background = 'olive';
} else {
    first.removeAttribute("style")
    second.removeAttribute("style")
    third.removeAttribute("style")
}
```